# How to run a hodges-lehmann test in R or SPSS

Tags: r

How can I compute the Hodges-Lehmann (aligned ranks) test in R or SPSS? Is there are ready-made functions to call? I understood the formula,but if the Hodges-Lehmann test has already been implemented, there would be no need to create a new function .

I tried `hodgeslehmann()` in the `senstrat` package, but it's not what I need. It only computes Hodges-Lehmann Aligned Ranks, but couldn't give the statistical value.

Answer (score 2):

An R version in a package called DescTools is documented [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/HodgesLehmann) and also [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/DescTools/man/HodgesLehmann.html).

Note especially that it will supply confidence intervals but only if you make use of the `conf.level` argument.

And there is SPSS Syntax code [here](http://www.spsstools.net/en/syntax/syntax-index/distributions/hodges-lehmann-confidence-interval-for-median-difference/), but you may prefer something that has had better open-source scrutiny.

Comment: It may help some greatly to know that the original article by Hodges and Lehmann is lucidly written and is available for free [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704172).